# Creating a json file from vb.net using public class with a dataset

Tags: json, vb.net

I need to create a JSON file using vb.net. I have no idea what to do except the following:

I created a public class with 4 fields :

```
    Public Class apikeys
    Public Property api_endpoint() As String
    Public Property api_id() As String
    Public Property api_key() As String
    Public Property customers As DataSet
    End Class
```

I then add data to the fields by doing the following in my main code:

```
    Dim objReq As New apikeys

    objReq.api_endpoint = "new_customers"
    objReq.api_id = "customerdatail"
    objReq.api_key = "appropriate key"

    objReq.customers = dataSet

    Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objReq, Formatting.Indented)
```

When I run the code I get the following in my JSON file:

```
  {
   "api_endpoint": "new_customers",
   "api_id": "customerdetail",
   "api_key": "appropriate key",
   "customers": {
   "customers": [
```

my problem is the section where i get :

```
"customers": {
   "customers": [
```

The first "customers" is from the class then second is the dataset name.

What can I do not to print the 1st `"customer" ; {` in the JSON file?

Comment: The first `customers` string is the Property name, the second is the Table name. Either change the name of the DataTable or use `Public Property customers As DataTable` and assign a Table in the DataSet to the property, so it's serialized as an array (the DataTable's name is not serialized, since it's supposed to be `customers`).

Comment: Thanks Jimi,, you are absolutely brilliant, worked like a charm.

Comment: First comment should be posted as the answer, I bet this is a common problem when using same name for different purposes.